# Node Express Ubuntu Pm2 | EADDRINUSE

Tags: express, pm2

I have a node express app running on Ubuntu with the pm2 service and nginx. All is fine starting up the pm2 service and my app is accessible. As soon as I navigate to another page on my app, `pm2 list` shows my app as `status: errored`. When I look at the error logs, I'm seeing a loop of:

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::4300`

I would think that I simply just need to find the service using `port 4300` and kill it, but that's becoming a problem. When I run `lsof -w -n -i tcp:4300` I do see a service running with an id of `23350`. When I then run `kill -15 23350`, that obviously kills the process, but a new service is started immediately. I have tried stopping, starting and restarting pm2 with no luck. When I stop pm2, I can't even run `npm run start` as I get `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::4300`.

Why is pm2 crashing upon navigating to another page on my app?
Why, when pm2 does crash, is it complaining about port 4300 already being in use?

*I should note that when `pm2 list` reports status: errored, my app is still accessible except for when the form on the /contact page is submitted. It submits to itself with `app.post('/contact'...)`, but in the browser, I see a blank white screen with 'Cannot post /contact'.*

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Is this solved?

Comment: Nope. Wasn't solved. I recently ended up moving operations to Heroku where this kind of functionality is handled. Thanks for asking.

Comment: You can get the ID from `pm2 list` and use `pm2 stop <id>` to stop the pm2 and then start the app normally using `node <filename>` and post the error in the question then we can resolve and run it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue (killing node process but another one spawns) and finally resolved it. I may use some wrong UNIX terminology, please correct me if I do.

I was running pm2 on an AWS EC2 instance, and the OS was Ubuntu 20.04.

My problem was that it appears that the root user's pm2 processes are separate from the ubuntu (default) user's. When I was the default user and ran `pm2 status`, I saw my one stopped node process. When I switched to the root user using `sudo su` and ran `pm2 status`, I found another pm2 process running that wasn't listed when I was the default user! So I ran `pm2 stop all` as the root user and that solved my issue.

Steps:

1. `sudo su # switch to root user`
2. `pm2 status # list all processes. For me this listed an extra running process that wasn't listed when I was the default user.`
3. I just ran `pm2 stop all` to stop all the root user processes. You can also just stop the specific running process if you want with `pm2 stop <name of pm2 process>`.

Hopefully that helps someone!